# Unknown column on 'on clause' in sql joins?

Tags: sql

Can you guys help me please in understanding the SQL specifications on join. I don't understand it. I kept getting errors called Unknown column list on on clause. 
I got this error over my SQL syntax, I almost rubbed it in my face I just can't understand why it is not working, I have read some article regarding that it is because of precedence etc but I am really confused on what I have done wrong here.

```
select product.name , product.price from product inner join product_category on          
(product_category.product_no = product.product_no ) where product_category.sub_category = 
"COFFIN";
```

I know this question have been ask a hudred and million times here, but the ones I saw are complicated nowhere close in this very basic sql syntax.

THanks for helping me out.

EDIT:
I just had realize that I have product_category not a direct child to my product table so
I just have typed

```
 select * from product 
 join specifications 
 join product_category on ( specifications.product_no = product_category.product_no);
```

But this still gave me an error, unknown column product_category.

I've read and followed some instruction similarly to this sites:
[MYSQL unknown clause join column in next join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13783669/mysql-unknown-clause-join-column-in-next-join)
[Unknown column {0} in on clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1753837/unknown-column-0-in-on-clause)
[MySQL "Unknown Column in On Clause"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10483421/mysql-unknown-column-in-on-clause)

I am really frustrated. I really can't get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified the SQL syntax to look like this, I have overlook a key that connects product_category onto specification so I made necessary link and it worked!!!

```
SELECT *
FROM product
JOIN specifications ON ( product.product_no = specifications.product_no )
JOIN product_category ON ( specifications.spec_no = product_category.spec_no )
WHERE product_category.sub_category = "COFFIN"
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Also thanks for the heads up on missing joining condition on specifications. Heck this carelessness cost so much time.
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 5):

For each new table you join in your query, each table must have at least one ON clause. It's hard to know exactly what you're trying to do without knowing the schema (table names, columns, etc), but here's an example

```
select *
from product p
join specifications s
    on p.product_no = s.product_no
join product_category pc
    on pc.spec_no = p.spec_no
```

Check out this link on table aliases as well. Gives a good example on joins + really useful info on how to increase the readability of your SQL
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187455(v=sql.90).aspx

I found this article useful as well as it visually displays  the different types of joins
http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Comment: you links are bookmarked! Wonderful! thanks! +1 on knowing schema, I finally made it to work and I completely overlook an important key that links the other table to the other.

Comment: Apparently this applies even if you didn't join in the other table.  Once you use a join you need a join for every extra table.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the part where you specify the joining conditions between product and specifcations.

```
select * from product 
join specifications YOU NEED SOMETHING HERE
join product_category on etc
```

Comment: Oh yes, I have tried that, with this one
select * from product 
join specifications on ( product.product_no = specifications.product_no )
join product_category on ( specifications.product_no = product_category.product_no);
 it still gave the error

Answer (score 1):

The default join type is an `inner join`.  So if you write `join`, the database reads `inner join`, and insist that you include an `on` clause.

If you'd like to join without a condition, specify the `cross join` explicitly:

```
 select  * 
 from    product p
 cross join 
         specifications s
 inner join 
         product_category pc 
 on      pc.product_no = p.product_no
 left join
         some_other_table sot
 on      1=1
```

The last join, with the `on 1=1` condition, is another way to do a `cross join`.  It's subtly different in that it will return rows from the left table even if the right table is empty.

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/91efd/2/0)